# Hiding Jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Jquery dialog script

```
 function SupplierGridPopup() {
    var dlg = $("#divSupplierGrid").dialog({ bgiframe: true,
        width: $(document).width(),
        height: $(document).height(),
        modal: true,
        focus: function () { hideScrollBars(); },
        open: function () { hideScrollBars(); },
        beforeClose: function () { showScrollBars(); }
    });
    dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
}
```

How to hide a Jquery modal dialog. As i have set modal to true just hiding div(i.e div.hide()) seems not working. I tried hiding using `$("#divSupplierGrid").dialog("option", "hide", 'slide');` statement. still its not working. How to hide the div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#divSupplierGrid").dialog('close'); // HIDEs the dialog`

`$("#divSupplierGrid").dialog('destroy'); // Remove the dialog functionality completely.`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#divSupplierGrid").dialog('close');
```

to close the dialog..and in doing that you will hide it